# Scala-Redis library is not included in the fat jar file

Tags: scala, redis, executable-jar

I am working on a scala standalone application which is updating Redis server(Executing this application as a Spark job). Scala version of my application is 2.10.

I am using "net.debasishg" % "redisclient_2.10" % "2.13" to work with Redis server.

I ran the application through the IntelliJ idea and application is running without any error. Then i create a jar of my application by giving "activator package" command. Then i execute the jar file, it is given error as follows,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/redis/RedisClient
at Main$.main(Main.scala:55)
at Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.redis.RedisClient
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 9 more
```

Please anyone have an idea how to overcome this issue. (I tried with sbt-assembly plugin unfortunately it is not resolve my issue)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this problem as follows,

1. Create a assembly.sbt file and added into the project directory of the application. This file is included "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.0" plugin.
2. Added following lines to the build.sbt file

   scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

   ```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.6" % "test",
    ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.0").
     exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet").
     exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.transaction").
     exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.mail").
     exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.activation").
     exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
     exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections").
     exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections").
     exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog"),
    ("org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % " 2.2.0").
     exclude("com.twitter", "parquet-column"),
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.2.0",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.2.0",
    "net.debasishg" % "redisclient_2.10" % "2.14"
    excludeAll(
     ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"),
     ExclusionRule(organization = "com.twitter")
    ) 
   )

   mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
     case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
     case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
     case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".properties" => MergeStrategy.first
     case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".xml" => MergeStrategy.first
     case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".class" => MergeStrategy.first
     case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".thrift" => MergeStrategy.first
     case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
     case "unwanted.txt" => MergeStrategy.discard
     case x => old(x)
    }
   }
   ```
3. Finally clean the application with "activator clean" command and then run "activator assembly" to package the project

Thanks